`Add a product` section is missing in Facebook Dashboard
I recently started a project, and the owner asked me to implement login with Instagram and fetch photos from Instagram However, I cannot see anything related to Instagram Basic Display in Facebook App Dashboard.

In my old app projects in Facebook, I see there is a Add a Product section which includes different   products that facebook offers. I also see App Mode in them where I cannot see that toggle switch in the problematic app.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

I published the app to see whether it will change, without some of my use cases, however, nothing changed.

Click the "Set up" button you find in that last screenshot ...?

@CBroe The second screenshot is from my abandoned project. I'm expecting something like that in the first screenshot.

Maybe you selected an unfitting app type? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/other-app-types#step-3--select-an-app-type

@Pozithron I am facing the same issue, Are you able to solve this?
